# Hibernate unit of work

Tags: hibernate, transactions, entity

I have two entities, entity1 & entity2 managed by Hibernate such that if there is an error in saving entity1, entity2 must not be saved. So, the unit of work here consists of two separate entities: either both get saved or neither gets saved. My current code looks something like this:

```
public int saveEntity1()
{
 a =1;
 begin session;
 start tx;
 save entity1;
 commit tx;
    when exception 
    rollback tx;
    a=0;
 return a; 
}

 public int saveEntity2()
 {
 a =1;
 begin session;
 start tx;
 save entity2;
 commit tx;
     when exception 
     rollback tx;
     a=0;
 return a; 
 }
```

In the client method:

```
 public void submitData()
 {
  int res = Entity1DAO.saveEntity1();
  if(res==1)
  {
  Entity2DAO.saveEntity2();
  }
 }
```

Could I persist the 2 entities within the same transaction, so i don't have to use the if statement in the client method?

Comment: Uhm, what language is this code?  Pseudocode?  Far better to excerpt from your actual source.

Answer (score 0):

You can write another method and start your transaction in it .

```
anotherMethod(){

      try{
      start tx;
      method1();
      method2();
      end tx;
      }catch(Exception e){
        rollBack tx;           
      }
         }
```